# What is going on in this Python for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
records = [
('foo', 1, 2),
('bar', 'hello'),
('foo', 3, 4),
]

def do_foo(x, y):
    print('foo', x, y)

def do_bar(s):
    print('bar', s)

for tag, *args in records:
    if tag == 'foo':
        do_foo(*args)
    elif tag == 'bar':
        do_bar(*args)
```

I know you can use syntax like `for i, val in enumerate(a)`. To me, it looks like `tag, *args` is being used here to create a tuple, such that the code is effectively `for tuple in records`. But that is just an uneducated guess.

Comment: I'll just note that `*args` as an assignment target in the loop (or indeed any assignment) is Python3-specific: this is a syntax error in Python 2.x.

Comment: Are there any good resources on Python 3 where this exact behavior is discussed?

Comment: The on line language and library references are the most definitive guides. http://docs.python.org/3/ (2.x is also on the same site)

Comment: @ZackGao it is described in [pep-3132](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), you can also google for 'python extended tuple unpacking'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`records` is a list of tuples, which the `for` statement iterates over. On each iteration, `tag` is assigned the first element of the tuple (the strings `'foo'` and `'bar'`), and `*args` sets `args` to a tuple consisting of the rest of the tuple (e.g. `(1, 2)`). These are then spread as arguments when calling `do_foo` and `do_bar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for tag, *args in records:
```

means taken each element in the iterable `records`. That element will be iterable.

Put the first element of that element in `tag`, and put the rest in a tuple named `args`.

```
do_foo(*args)
```

means pass of the members of `args` to `do_foo` as arguments.

So the list

```
records = [
    ('foo', 1, 2),
    ('bar', 'hello'),
    ('foo', 3, 4),
]
```

causes

```
foo(1, 2)
bar('hello')
foo(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature available in Python 3+.

```
a,*b=[1,2,3,4]
print(a)
>>>1
print(b)
>>>[2,3,4]
```

Similarly,

```
a,*b,c=('foo',1,2,3,4)
print(a)
>>>'foo'
print(b)
>>>[1,2,3]
print(c)
>>>4
```

The python interpreter creates a list of appropriate size for the variable beginning with `*`. I hope the purpose of `*args` in the above loop is now clear.